# Unable to install gold linker

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, binutils

It seems I can't install gold linker for 13.10 anymore:

```
$ sudo apt-get install binutils-gold
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'binutils' instead of 'binutils-gold'
binutils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 276 not upgraded
```

I see [this with lots of 'removal' notices](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/binutils-gold). WTH? I already tried `apt-get update` and doesn't help

**Edit** the same problem happens with Trusty (14.04)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gold` linker is now in the `binutils` package instead of `binutils-gold` (which is what `apt-get` is trying to tell you). Since you already have the package, you have the linker.

Comment: What about on Debian? How can I find this linker?